# Loop through nodes and append value to a string using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML. Under the root node I have 'Search' node which holds configuration and 'Req' node which has Request. Inside 'Req' node there is a 'classId' node. I am storing the value  I have a complex problem here. I have a 'appendString' node in my final result. First I need to check if a child node inside 'Req' node has value in it. If it has value I need to get the node name and match the node inside AllClass/class1/node3 and get its value and finally I need to form a String inside 'appendString' node like this **'Childname1=value1,Childname2=value2'**. Please help.Thanks

My XML

```
<root>
  <ns:Search xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/">
    <ns:AllClass>
      <ns:class1>
        <ns:node1>fhgfjh</ns:node1>
        <ns:node2>Aprtyrtyril</ns:node2>
        <ns:node3>
            <ns:firstChild>Childname1</ns:firstChild>
            <ns:SecondChild>Childname2</ns:SecondChild>
        </ns:node3>
      </ns:class1>
      <ns:class2>
        <ns:node1>dfgd</ns:node1>
        <ns:node2>trytyu</ns:node2>
        <ns:node3>
            <ns:firstChild>Childname11</ns:firstChild>
            <ns:SecondChild>Childname22</ns:SecondChild>
            <ns:ThirdChild>Childname33</ns:ThirdChild>
        </ns:node3>
      </ns:class2>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
    </ns:AllClass>
  </ns:Search>
  <ns:Req xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/">
    <ns:classId>class1</ns:classId>
    <ns:className>asdfg</ns:className>
    <ns:firstChild>value1</ns:firstChild>
    <ns:SecondChild>value2</ns:SecondChild>
    <ns:ThirdChild></ns:ThirdChild>
    <ns:FourthChild></ns:FourthChild>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  </ns:Req>
</root>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="root/Req">
    <xsl:variable xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/" name="class_tmp" select="/root/ns:Req/ns:classId" />
    <xsl:variable name="class" select="concat(&apos;ns:&apos;,$class_tmp)" />
    <ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns/">
      <ns1:SearchString>
        <xsl:value-of xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/1.0/" select="/root/ns:Search/ns:AllClassM/*[name()=$class]/ns:node2" />
      </ns1:SearchString>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ns1:Response>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root/Req/*">
    <ns1:appendString></ns1:appendString>
  </xsl:template>
```

Final XML

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns/">
<ns1:SearchString>Aprtyrtyril</ns1:SearchString>
<ns1:appendString>Childname1=value1,Childname2=value2</ns1:appendString>
</ns1:Response>
```

Comment: attach your sample expected result XML

Comment: @nawazlj Added sample XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***---  edited in response to clarifications ---***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/"
xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="ns:AllClass/*" use="name()" />
<xsl:key name="label" match="ns:node3/*" use="concat(name(), '|', name(../..))" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="classId" select="concat('ns:', ns:Req/ns:classId)" />
    <ns1:Response>
        <ns1:SearchString>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('id', $classId)/ns:node2" />
        </ns1:SearchString>
        <ns1:appendString>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns:Req/*[not(self::ns:classId or self::ns:className)][text()]">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('label', concat(name(), '|', $classId))" />
                <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:appendString>
    </ns1:Response>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes any node under `ns:Req` except `ns:classId` and `ns:className` is a "child node" that needs to be listed if not empty.

Comment: Thanks I will check

Comment: Its working correctly, I am using the second way. But I wanted it a bit different. I want to get the value of 'node3' of the class that I am passing inside '<ns:classId></ns:classId> ' this node. the values inside firstChild or secondChild maybe different for different class and the 'appendString' should contain only the nodes present inside 'node3' even if all nodes inside 'Req' has values in it

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I *think* you want the `appendString` to take the "labels" (Childname1, Childname2) from node3 of the node specified in `ns:classId`? But I don't know what you mean by "*the values inside firstChild or secondChild maybe different for different class and the 'appendString' should contain only the nodes present inside 'node3' even if all nodes inside 'Req' has values in it*".

Comment: Example 
1.if classId = class1
then
appendString => Childname1=value1,Childname2=value2

2. if classId = class2
then
appendString => Childname11=value1,Childname22=value2,Childname33=value3

I have updated the XML

Comment: I want the classId before node3, so instead of 
<xsl:key name="label" match="ns:node3/*" use="name()" />
it should be 
<xsl:key name="label" match="ns:(name of  class)/ns:node3/*" use="name()" />

Comment: I have edited my answer to do what I think you want (still not sure I get it right).

Comment: Thanks Michael, It is almost working the way I expected, I think I will do the changes required. Still I will describe what I wanted. 

Let's assume all the child node inside `ns:Req` has values inside them

So, when I am passing **class1** as `classId` I am getting the following string 

`Childname1=value1,Childname2=value2,=value3,=value4` because class1/node3 has only 2 nodes, I wanted just this `Childname1=value1,Childname2=value2`

Comment: or if I am passing **class3** as `classId`(note: class3 is not present in my XML) I am getting `=value1,=value2,=value3,=value4` Instead I should get an empty string.

Comment: @SMAhmed This is why I originally went in the opposite direction.

Comment: I have added the working XSLT going the opposite direction as suggested by you

Answer (score 0):

Going in the opposite direction as suggested earlier by Michael, below is the working XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/"
xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="id" match="ns:AllClass/*" use="name()" />
<xsl:key name="req" match="ns:Req/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="root">
<xsl:variable name="classId" select="concat('ns:', ns:Req/ns:classId)" />
    <ns1:Response>
        <ns1:SearchString>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('id', $classId)/ns:node2" />
        </ns1:SearchString>
        <ns1:appendString>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('id', $classId)/ns:node3/*">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('req',name())" />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:appendString>
    </ns1:Response>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```